# Uploading a webpage made via Laravel on a core PHP based website

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

How to upload a Laravel based webpage on PHP server? The main website is coded in core PHP and I made a webpage using Laravel. The guy working with uploading of the webpages didn't know how to integrate it either?
**Tell me How can I upload a webpage coded via Laravel on a PHP server?**

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is a PHP framework and individual Laravel webpages do not exist - you define routes and use a controller method to direct the request to an appropriate view or response ([look up MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)). If you made just a single route, controller and view and you want that html on your live site you could just copy the generated page source into a static html file. You will also need any stylesheets and scripts that go with it. This is a bad idea in terms of maintainability and ease of deployment though. You should either make your entire site (or section of your site) in Laravel or not at all.

Alternatively you will need to install your Laravel application on your web server by following [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/installation).